# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') when implementing LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, data

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="filters" icon-name="standard:calibration">
    <div class="slds-m-horizontal_medium">
        <lightning-input label="Search Key" type="search"
            onchange={handleSearchKeyChange} value={filters.searchKey}>

        </lightning-input>
        <section class="slider_section">
            <lightning-slider label="Max Price" step="100" min="500"
                max="999999"
                value={filters.maxprice} onchange={handleMaxPriceChange}></lightning-slider>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h2>Category</h2>
            <template if:true={categories.data}>
                <template for:each={categories.data.values}
                    for:item="category">
                    <lightning-input key={category.value}
                        label={category.label} type="checkbox" checked
                        name="category"
                        onchange={handleCheckbox}></lightning-input>
                </template>
            </template>

            <template if:true={categories.error}>
                <div>{categoryError}</div>
            </template>
        </section>
         <section>
            <h2>Maker</h2>
            <template if:true={makeType.data}>
                <template for:each={makeType.data.values} for:item="make">
                    <lightning-input key={make.value} label={make.label}
                        type="checkbox" checked
                        name="makeType"
                        onchange={handleCheckbox}></lightning-input>
                </template>
            </template>

            <template if:true={makeType.error}>
                <div>{makeError}</div>
            </template>
        </section>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
```

**and below is the javascript file here**

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo,  getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import VEHICLE_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Vehicle__c'

// car schema import work i have done here
import CATEGORY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Vehicle__c.Category__c'
import MAKE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Vehicle__c.Manufacturer__c'
//here i am adding some constants for error show
const CATEGORY_ERROR='ERROR Loading Categories'
const MAKE_ERROR='ERROR Loading maker'

export default class BikeFilter extends LightningElement {

    filters={
        searchKey: '',
        maxprice:999999
    }
    categoryError=CATEGORY_ERROR
    makeError=MAKE_ERROR
    /***fetching Category picklist */
    @wire(getObjectInfo, {objectApiName:VEHICLE_OBJECT})
    bikeObjectInfo;


    @wire(getPicklistValues,{
        recordTypeId:'$bikeObjectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeID',
        fieldApiName:CATEGORY_FIELD
    })categories;
    /***fetching Manufacturer picklist */
    
     @wire(getPicklistValues,{
      recordTypeId:'$bikeObjectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeID',
        fieldApiName:MAKE_FIELD
     })maketype;


handleSearchKeyChange(){

}
handleMaxPriceChange(){

}
handleCheckbox(){

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML, check if `categories` and `makeType` are not undefined before reading `categories.data` and `makeType.data`.

```html
<template if:true={categories}>
    <template if:true={categories.data}>
        <!--rest of the code-->
    </template>
</template>

<template if:true={makeType}>
    <template if:true={makeType.data}>
        <!--rest of the code-->
    </template>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the two `getPicklistValues` wired adapter: they are called before `bikeObjectInfo` is retrieved, so it's still `undefined`, thus the error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

You could define a getter for the `defaultRecordTypeId` to fix this. By the way, Javascript is case-sensitive, so `defaultRecordTypeId` and `defaultRecordTypeID` are not the same.

```js
get defaultRecordTypeId() {
    return this.bikeObjectInfo?.data?.defaultRecordTypeId;
}


@wire(getPicklistValues,{
    recordTypeId:'$defaultRecordTypeId',
    fieldApiName:CATEGORY_FIELD
})
categories;
    
@wire(getPicklistValues,{
    recordTypeId:'$defaultRecordTypeId',
    fieldApiName:MAKE_FIELD
})
maketype;
```

[`?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is the optional chaining operator and returns `undefined` instead of throwing an error if the object accessed is `null` or `undefined`.

Finally both sections for category and maker should be rendered only when the related properties are available, so you should add a [`lwc:if`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-conditional.html) directive.
Please note that `if:true` and `if:false` directive have been deprecated.

```html
<section lwc:if={categories}>
    <h2>Category</h2>
    other code
</section>
<section lwc:if={maketype}>
    <h2>Maker</h2>
```

Comment: yes this helped me a lot but the make picklist is not visible! that is not rendering

Comment: @SomankarChakraborty could you please edit the question updating the code you're using now? Maybe there's a typo somewhere.